# .get() method failing in Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, node.js

I am trying to access and style the different objects inside a **jQuery object** by using .get(); and I have been successful in simply accessing the individual objects but unable to perform operations like **adding css or classes to those** individual elements. I also tried to use [] to access and style; but **access is again a success while I am not being able to style that selected element**. Why is this happening?

**my script using .get()** =>

```js
$(()=>{
  $('button').click(function(event){
    $(".box div").get(1).toggleClass('color');
  });
});
```

```css
.box{
  font-size: 0px;
  width: min-content;
}

.color{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<button>click</button>
```

> TypeError: $(...).get(...).toggleClass is not a function

Why is this message coming? How to resolve this and ***get specific index element*** from a jQuery Object?

Answer (score 0):

i hope this helps you.

```js
$(()=>{
  $('button').click(function(event){
    $(".box div:nth-child(1)").toggleClass('color');
  });
});
```

```css
.box{
  font-size: 0px;
  width: min-content;
}

.color{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<button>click</button>
```

Comment: It's amazing. But can you tell me why .get() is failing?

Comment: @PrabhdeepSingh i guess the reason is toggle class will only work if you only get the root element you want to change as a parent. just like :  $('div') instread of $('.box div'). but if you still want use this:  $('.box div') you need to do this : $(".box div").get(1).setAttribute('class', 'color').